# Syntax error in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Keeps saying that there is an unexpected if, but nothing I change is accepted.

```
addAnimation : (anim) ->
    if anim.time > @animations[@animations.length - 1]
        @animations.push(anim)
    else if anim.time < @animations[0]
        @animations.unshift(anim)
    else
        for index in [1..@animations.length]
            if anim.time > @animations[index-1].time
            and anim.time < @animations[index]
                @animations.splice(index, 0, anim)
                    break
```

All the spacing is as correct as possible. I use 4 for all indentation and there is no trailing whitespace. Have I misunderstood something about the syntax. Btw, this is supposed to be a simple insertion sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the `and` inline and remove the extra indentation on the `break` statement then it works fine.

```
addAnimation : (anim) ->
    if anim.time > @animations[@animations.length - 1]
        @animations.push(anim)
    else if anim.time < @animations[0]
        @animations.unshift(anim)
    else
        for index in [1...@animations.length] by 1
            if anim.time > @animations[index-1].time and 
            anim.time < @animations[index]
                @animations.splice(index, 0, anim)
                break
```

The key is that CoffeeScript will not interpret the next line as the body of the statement if the line ends with an operator, so if you want your `if` statement to span multiple lines then you must end each line with an operator:

```
if a and 
b and
not c
  do something
```

Whereas this will not compile:

```
if a
and b 
not c
  do nothing
```